# Accessibility in Google Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, accessibility

So I'm  working on updating an angular 4 application to meet WCAG AA conformance for accessibility.  One thing that's important in accessibility is alt text for images, and I thought for buttons as well.  So I took the existing button and added an input for alt text so the parent could inform it which kind of button it is and add the context through the alt text.

When I run the project in NVDA & Firefox it catches the alt text and reads it, but in chrome with NVDA it doesn't.  So then since aria-label and title are inconsistent with buttons as well I just add a hidden span to the button text, which gets read in Chrome, but overwrites the alt text in Firefox.

We will be getting audited by a group who uses NVDA/Firefox and JAWS/IE, but our lead likes Chrome and our client's users like chrome as well.  Do I program for chrome with a hammer, or use the different tags and stuff for the other 2?

Comment: Can you clarify what your HTML looks like - perhaps add a fragment? You mention 'input' above - did you mean 'img'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using hidden text (like the bootstrap `sr-only` class) is *the correct method* for what you're doing.

The `alt` attribute is not intended for use on button elements, and the [HTML 5.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#alt) does not permit it. It may work in some browser & screen reader combinations, but I certainly wouldn't rely on it.

Chrome has a reputation as being among the least accessible browsers. I wouldn't worry about getting it to work perfectly. As long as you code to the specification, you're doing the right thing.

Just for completeness, here are some [techniques for creating screen-reader only content](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/).

Comment: Ended up going with this but it's good to see reasons for backing it up.  Thanks.